# Looping through the data from database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hey I have got data in my variable using foreach($report as &rep)

note it is getting things from 4 different table in database

Now when I print my $rep I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [Report] => Array
        (
            [id] => 246
            [emp] => werock
            [name] => werock
            [organization] => cakephp
            [customer] => great
        )

    [file] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 211
                    [report_id] => 246
                    [file_name] => 
                    [file_type] => 
                    [file_size] => 0
                    [file_error] => 4
                    [file_tag] => 0
                )

        )

    [Engineer] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 232
                    [report_id] => 246
                )

        )

    [Issue] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 118
                    [report_id] => 246
                    [date_created] => 2012-02-10
                    [status] => wait
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 119
                    [report_id] => 246
                    [date_created] => 2012-02-10
                    [status] => debug
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 120
                    [report_id] => 246
                    [date_created] => 2012-02-10
                    [status] => Completed

                )

        )

)
```

Now what I want to do is access Issues array and check how many array are there in it. in this case 3(0,1,2). and print the value of status for the last index in this case(2).

But when I do $rep['Issue']['status'] I get Undefined index: status. Can you tell me where I might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
echo $rep['Issue'][count($rep['Issue'])-1]['status'];
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$rep['Issue'][$x]['status']
```

Where $x is variable you can use in a loop to get values.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second index.  It should be:

`$rep['Issue'][count($rep['Issue'])-1]['status']`.

You could also try using [Set::extract](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1501/extract) instead.  The Set class is very useful for working with arrays.

```
$status = Set::extract('/Issue/.[:last]/status', $rep);
if(count($status)){
 // $status[0] == the value of status which is 'Complete' in your example
} else {
 // no issues
}
```

Comment: the set:: extract is actually fetching the first record instead of the last.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I tested this code yesterday with the array you posted and Set::extract fetched the last record (i.e. $status[0] == 'Complete').

Answer (score -1):

I tried another method if just thought of sharing.

$endEl[$rep['Report']['id'] ] = end($rep['Issue'] );

let me know if it's a good way.. it works